# Flex 3 - Enable context menu for text object under a transparent PNG

Tags: flex3, png, contextmenu

Here is the situation. In my app I have an overlay layer that is composed of a transparent PNG. I have replaced the hitarea for the png with a 1x1 image using the following code:

```
[Bindable]
[Embed(source = "/assets/1x1image.png")]
private var onexonebitmapClass:Class;

private function loadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
{
    // Create the bitmap
    var onexonebitmap:BitmapData = new onexonebitmapClass().bitmapData;
    var bitmap:Bitmap;
    bitmap = event.target.content as Bitmap;
    bitmap.smoothing = true;
    var _hitarea:Sprite = createHitArea(onexonebitmap, 1);
    var rect:flash.geom.Rectangle = _box.toFlexRectangle(sprite.width, sprite.height);
    var drawnBox:Sprite = new FlexSprite();

    bitmap.width = rect.width;
    bitmap.height = rect.height;
    bitmap.x = -loader.width / 2;
    bitmap.y = -loader.height / 2;
    bitmap.alpha = _alpha;
    _hitarea.alpha = 0;
    drawnBox.x = rect.x + rect.width / 2;
    drawnBox.y = rect.y + rect.height / 2;

    // Add the bitmap as a child to the drawnBox
    drawnBox.addChild(bitmap);

    // Rotate the object.
    drawnBox.rotation = _rotation;

    // Add the drawnBox to the sprite
    sprite.addChild(drawnBox);

    // Set the hitarea to drawnBox
    drawnBox.hitArea = _hitarea;

}


private function createHitArea(bitmapData:BitmapData, grainSize:uint = 1):Sprite
{
    var _hitarea:Sprite = new Sprite();
    _hitarea.graphics.beginFill(0x900000, 1.0);
    for (var x:uint = 0; x < bitmapData.width; x += grainSize)
    {
        for (var y:uint = grainSize; y < bitmapData.height; y += grainSize)
        {
            if (x <= bitmapData.width && y <= bitmapData.height && bitmapData.getPixel(x, y) != 0)
            {
                _hitarea.graphics.drawRect(x, y, grainSize, grainSize);
            }
        }
    }
    _hitarea.graphics.endFill();
    return _hitarea;
}
```

This is based off the work done here: [Creating a hitarea for PNG Image with transparent (alpha) regions in Flex](http://www.webverwirklichung.com/en/blog/programming/flex/creating-hitarea-png-image-transparent-alpha-regions-flex)

Using the above code I am able to basically ignore the overlay layer for all mouse events (click, double click, move, etc.) However, I am unable to capture the right click (context menu) event for items that are beneath the overlay.

For instance I have a spell check component that checks the spelling on any textitem and like most other spell checkers if the word is incorrect or not in the dictionary underlines the word in red and if you right click on it would give you a list of suggestions in the contextmenu. This is working great when the text box is not under the overlay, but if the text box is under the overlay I get nothing back.

If anyone can give me some pointers on how to capture the right click event on a textItem that is under a transparent png that would be great.